# Filtering data causes items not displayed on android

Tags: c#, linq, xamarin.forms

I am getting some data and then I have to filter it based on requirements. I use it in a Xamarin Application. This is my view model loading the data and filtering them. There are two scenarios: I either load all data or just some. This works on iOS, however on android it doesn't. The data is displayed once, then when I load the page again it is not. Seems to be a mistake in filtering the data, so maybe I am overdoing it?

The approach I decided to go for was to have multiple lists, then just transfer data from one to another.

```
private List < Item > _filtredItems = new List < Item > ();
private List < TextFormField > _resultsWithDiacriticListToTransform = new List < TextFormField > ();

private List < TextFormField > _results = new List < TextFormField > ();
private List < TextFormField > _allResults = new List < TextFormField > ();
private ObservableCollection < ImageResult > _imageResults = new ObservableCollection < ImageResult > ();
private ObservableCollection < ImageFormField > _imageResultsToDB = new ObservableCollection < ImageFormField > ();

if (processIdentityGeneratedData.ProcessIdenityDocument is List < Item > item) {

  foreach(var result in item) {

    switch (result) {
    case ImageFormField imageField: {
      imageField.ID = ProcessIdentityDocumentService.ReturnId();
      var imageResult = new ImageResult() {
        VisualResult = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(imageField.EncodedImage.EncodedData))),
      };

      _imageResults.Add(imageResult);

      if (_imageResultsToDB.All(a => a.FieldType != imageField.FieldType)) {
        _imageResultsToDB.Add(imageField);
      }

      if (_imageResults.Count > 1) {
        IsEnabled = true;
      }

      CalculateImageSize(imageField.Height, imageField.Width);

      break;
    }
    case TextFormField textField: {
      textField.ID = ProcessIdentityDocumentService.ReturnId();
      _resultsWithDiacriticListToTransform.Add(textField);
      _allResults = _localizationOfResults.ReturnNotNormalized(_resultsWithDiacriticListToTransform);
      //LineBreakMode didnt work so we have to add new line once the Text value is longer than 28
      if (textField.Text.Length > 28 && !DeviceManager.IsATabletDevice()) {
        textField.Text = _processIdentityDocumentService.NewLineConvertor(textField.Text);
      }

      break;
    }

    }

  }
}

switch (_includeFields.Mode) {

case IncludeFieldsMode.selective:

  _filtredItems.AddRange(_imageResultsToDB);

  var list = _allResults.Where(a => _includeFields.Fieldtype.Contains(a.FieldType)).ToList();

  var listForSingleItems = _allResults.Where(a => a.FieldType == IdentityDocumentFieldType.Surname_And_Given_Names || a.FieldType == IdentityDocumentFieldType.Date_of_Expiry || a.FieldType == IdentityDocumentFieldType.DocumentType).ToList();
  var listWithoutSingleData = list.Except(listForSingleItems);

  _filtredItems.AddRange(listWithoutSingleData.Where(a => a.FieldType != IdentityDocumentFieldType.Date_of_Expiry));
  _filtredItems.AddRange(listForSingleItems);

  if (_filtredItems.Count <= 0) {
    log.Debug("NoDataRecognized");
    break;
  }

  LoadSingleData(listForSingleItems);
  Results.Load(list.Where(i => i.Description != null).ToList());

  break;

case IncludeFieldsMode.includeAllFields:

  _filtredItems.AddRange(_imageResultsToDB);
  _filtredItems.AddRange(_allResults);
  Results.Load(_allResults.Where(i => i.Description != null).ToList());
  LoadSingleData(_allResults);
  break;

}
```

Comment: what have you done to debug this?  Have you compared the results of the filter algorithm on both platforms to verify they are behaving identically?  I'd guess the problem is more likely in how you are refreshing your UI, but you didn't post any of that code so its impossible to say.

Comment: yes, I tested it once I didn't filter anything and just returned the data , it was ok.

Comment: If you think the problem is with the filtering, have you tested the **filtering logic** and compared the results on both platforms **using the debugger** to verify that the behavior is the same on both platforms?

Comment: yes, the behavior is the same, I tested it and I debugged it. Otherwise I would not post it here.

Comment: then the problem is not in your filtering logic, and is more likely a UI issue.  But you only posted the filtering code.

Comment: First, I don't see `_filtredItems.Clear();` anywhere. Second, If you are attempting to display `_filtredItems`, then it must be an `ObservableCollection` and a `Property` -- `{ get; } = new ObservableCollection<Item>();`. Otherwise, dynamic changes may not work. Third, when changing the entire list, I recommend replacing the list with a new list (`_filtredItems = tempList;`, where you first add all the items to tempList)  - if you try to add/delete many items from the existing list, UI update performance will be poor.